# Scope of a VBA object declared and initialised in for() cycle

Tags: class, vba, scope

I have a class "Portfolio" (which has class "Stock" as one of it's fields) method with following code:

```
For i = 1 To n
    Dim TempStock As New Stock
    TempStock.Set_Stock            'sets TempStock    
    ...
Next i
```

Where "Stock" is my user-defined classes with such structure, constructor and destructors:

```
Private StockName As String
Private CurDate As Date
Private BidPrice As Double
Private AskPrice As Double
Private StockDivs As Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set StockDivs = New Dictionary
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set StockDivs = Nothing
End Sub
```

I meant that in every loop I will declare and initialise new temp objects with empty fields. But after running my programm step-by-step it seems to me that Class_Terminate() is not called at the end of the loop. And on the next step all fields of `TempStock` are already set as they were on a previous loop. So, I don't understnad the following:

1) Why isn't `Class_Terminate()` called at `Next i`? When it is called? Is it written correctly now? Or should I also write code to set every non-object filed to it's null value?

2) Ok, it isn't called but I still have `Dim TempStock As New Stock`? Shouldn't it give me double declaration fault? Or set `TempStock` to new empty object at least?

3) What is the difference between:

```
 Dim TempStock As New Stock
```

and:

```
 Dim TempStock As Stock
 Set TempStock = New Stock
```

does it relate to my problem?

Help on any part of my problem would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no block level scope in VBA; all declarations (`dim`) are hoisted to the top of the containing procedure and only go out of scope at the end of the routine.

You are correct in that the behaviour you see is down to `As New`, currently the class will be instantiated once within the loop & not terminate until it drops out of scope when the procedure returns.

To get the behaviour you want you must use:

```
 Dim TempStock As Stock
 Set TempStock = New Stock
```

because it is the `set` that explicitly forces a new object instance to be assigned to `TempStock`

As declarations are hoisted, the line `Dim TempStock As New Stock` does not actually immediately create a new instance of `Stock`, rather this way of object creation inserts stub code for every call across a variable of type `Stock` that says "if I am not a valid reference, auto-create me now".

Comment: But what happens to "old" TempStock object on the second loop at that moment: Set TempStock = New Stock? Is Class_Terminate() called?

Comment: A 2nd call to `Set TempStock = New Stock` causes class_initialize on the new instance, followed by class_terminate on the existing one.

Comment: The Class_Terminate is an event that gets automatically called when the reference count reaches zero. Since variable Tempstock is assigned a "new" object on the heap on each loop, the previous object is released and the destructor on that (released) object gets called. TempStock is declared to hold a class object, thus cannot hold multiple instances such as a collection can.

Comment: Ah, I get it! I had another object further in the code which had a reference to TempStock, so the destructor wasn't called immediately after "New" but is called when that reference is terminated.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply the syntax:

```
Dim TempStock As Stock
Set TempStock = New Stock
```

the destructor gets called.
Object destruction in VBA happens when the reference count with the referenced object is brought to zero (nothing).
In this case, on every loop, you use the same variable "TempStock" to instantiate an entirely *new* "Stock" object which causes the previous object to be released from memory.

This piece of code is unnecessary, since the object will be destroyed anyway:

```
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set StockDivs = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you set StockDivs *explicitly* to nothing in the main sub, you will notice that the Class_Terminate event will be called, so in this case the object receives another release message for a second time while the reference count was already zero (otherwise this event would not have been called).

Regarding:

```
Dim TempStock As New Stock
```

According to the Microsoft, both formulas are equivalent:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa903373

However, equivalent does not mean they are identical.
Using the New keyword directly in the declaration will indeed also instantiate the Stock object, but as you have noticed, the constructor is only called once, and the destructor will only get called at the end of the loop. This implicitly means that you use the same object over and over again on each loop while reassigning properties on the same object (but without actually releasing it).
Also what is typical to this formulation is the fact that the initializer on the object is not called at declaration time, but only after its first use.
In most use cases, both can be used with the same result in the end.

My guess what you may be useful is the code below. 
Unless you want to add multiple stocks to a collection (you can also use a dictionary), I don't see the immediate reason to loop through the same class multiple times while assigning properties.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Stocks()

Dim oCollection         As Collection
Dim TempStock           As Stock
Dim lCnt                As Long


Set oCollection = New Collection

For lCnt = 1 To 5

    Set TempStock = New Stock

    TempStock.Set_Stock ("Stock_" & lCnt)       'sets TempStock name eg. 
    oCollection.Add TempStock
Next lCnt

End Sub
```

Where you add multiple stocks into a collection.